# Getting call SIM options disabled in ACTION_CALL

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been using ACTION_CALL in my app to direct call a number without opening dialpad with Phone Permission.

It working fine in general but in some devices with dual SIM and call settings set for Always Ask causing issue.

In some device when we open ACTION_CALL intent,it opens the dialog for user to choose which SIM to be use for call. In some cases, both this options are disabled as shown in image. We are using following code

```
    private void openCallIntent(String number, boolean needCountryCode) {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        if(needCountryCode) {
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+" + number));
        }else{
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        }
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
        //Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: some issue im facing

Answer (score 0):

I am not a developer but found this thread while searching Google for a similar problem I am having as user. It seems that as of versione v108 of Google Phone app (regardless of the device: I have tested on Xiaomi and Pixel) a bug must have been introduced for SIM selection in case of DUAl SIM and "Ask First" is set in the options. But as a user this happens only if I use Google Assistant to place a call saying "Het Google call xyz", if instad I use dialer or contact app, all works fine. I have this issue also if I search for a business activity on Google and I click on the dialer icon. reverting back to v107 solves the problem.